# How to use BITS in Powershell to upload / download files?

Tags: powershell-2.0, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I've found some pages in Google regarding this, but they are either not complete or outdated. Is there a definite guide somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is always the help within PowerShell:

```
PS> import-module bitstransfer
PS> gcm *bits* | ? {$_.Commandtype -eq "cmdlet"}

CommandType Name                  Definition
----------- ----                  ----------
Cmdlet      Add-BitsFile          Add-BitsFile [-BitsJob] <BitsJob[]> [-S...
Cmdlet      Complete-BitsTransfer Complete-BitsTransfer [-BitsJob] <BitsJ...
Cmdlet      Get-BitsTransfer      Get-BitsTransfer [[-Name] <String[]>] [...
Cmdlet      Remove-BitsTransfer   Remove-BitsTransfer [-BitsJob] <BitsJob...
Cmdlet      Resume-BitsTransfer   Resume-BitsTransfer [-BitsJob] <BitsJob...
Cmdlet      Set-BitsTransfer      Set-BitsTransfer [-BitsJob] <BitsJob[]>...
Cmdlet      Start-BitsTransfer    Start-BitsTransfer [-Source] <String[]>...
Cmdlet      Suspend-BitsTransfer  Suspend-BitsTransfer [-BitsJob] <BitsJo...
```

tells you the commands that are available.

You can then call `Get-Help` on those. The help entries are pretty helpful, from what I've seen. And don't forget `Get-Help ... -Examples` for detailed and annotated usage examples.  And the cmdlets are named self-explanatory, already.

Comment: Note to add: You can use `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to find out what modules you can import.

Comment: A better way to do this is to look at the commandlets in the module. In this case, gcm -module bitstransfer is a better way to look at the group.

Comment: Note: This doesn't (yet) seem to be supported on PowerShell Core: `import-module : Module 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\bitstransfer\bitstransfer.psd1' does not support current PowerShell edition 'Core'.` (I know the question is tagged for PowerShell 2.0 - just a heads-up for anyone looking for a Core solution).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the BITS file transfer Powerpack in case you need some kind of GUI around those BITS Cmdlets.

http://powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=2583&categoryID=21

Comment: It's not PowerShell, but the BITS team has made a sample C# app to let you view and control make aspects of BITS transfers.Take a look on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/bits-manager) for the app (there's an installer for the sample EXE). If you're a C# programmer, take a look at the new C# docs at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/bits-dot-net)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look into the JAMS Job Scheduler PowerShell cmdlets for File transfers. It makes it simple to manage transfers across different platforms.

Comment: Can you add some more detail which will make this a better answer?